# On webkit browsers, my main content div doesn't adjust the hight properly to fit the inner divs

Tags: html, css

This is my website http://www.miloads.com/

You can see the problem pretty easily lol. I have been up and down my css file and just can't figure it out!

Here's a link to my css file:

http://www.miloads.com/sites/all/themes/cmsflare/css/cmsflare.css

Also the header is larger than on firefox/ie and if you click on learn more it also acts weirdly on webkit browsers. These are minor issues though.

Any help would be INSANELY appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is it that learn more thing - or is it the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an in-line style set in your mark up which is preventing the inner div from growing. Removing the fixed height will show the inner content correctly. Probably why you cant see it in the CSS also.

```
<div class="block-inner" style="height: 1059px;">
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked!!! I also fixed my header problem. Only problem I have left is with the slide out tab acting weirdly.